# Jupyter notebook: error installing R packages

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, jupyter-notebook, libstdc++

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

I have R running on my Jupyter notebook and all the packages comes with "R essentials" work fine.

However, when I try to install additional packages like "mice" or "bigmemory", the installation always fails. When it tries to do

> ** testing if installed package can be loaded

this is the error message that appears:

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/R/library/bigmemory/libs/bigmemory.so':
>     /home/usr/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/libs/../../../../libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/usr/anaconda3/lib/R/library/bigmemory/libs/bigmemory.so)

I have tried `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6`
and it says my libstdc++6 is installed and already is the newest version. I don't know why the R installer cannot find it..

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out!

I got frustrated and uninstalled anaconda3 completely `rm -rf ~\anaconda3`. After reinstalling it, I looked at the instruction for [installing IRkernel](http://irkernel.github.io/installation/#binary-panel). I saw this:

> If this fails, search the output for something like:
>
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded
>   Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
>     unable to load shared object '/Users/[you]/anaconda/lib/R/library/rzmq/libs/rzmq.so':
>     dlopen(/Users/[you]/anaconda/lib/R/library/rzmq/libs/rzmq.so, 6): Library not loaded: libzmq.5.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/[you]/anaconda/lib/R/library/rzmq/libs/rzmq.so
>     Reason: image not found
>
> This would mean that the R binary package of rzmq was compiled against a different version of libzmq from the one on your system.
>   It can be fixed by installing from source

So following the instruction I then did 
`install.packages('mice','/home/[usr]/anaconda3/lib/R/library/',type = 'source')`

It worked! I did the same thing for 'bigmemory'. No error message and I can use them both on Jupyter notebook now.

Comment: Thanks  create an env for r workspace, it's less confusing.